# does this try-catch-with-resourcers autoclose?

Tags: java

Does this try-catch-with-resources auto-close?
It has a `return` in the body before it reaches the end.
Will it still auto-close the stream?

```
    try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(characterFile)) {
        final SavedPlayer savedPlayer = GSON.fromJson(reader, SavedPlayer.class);

        return new Login(player, LoginType.SUCCESSFUL);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new Login(player, LoginType.INPUT_FAILURE);
    }
```

Comment: AFAKI `try-with-resources` is somewhat like `try-finally`, where the close operation is guaranteed to always be executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes.

The [`try-with-resources` Statement (Java Tutorials)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) reads (in part)

> The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement.

Comment: "is closed at the end of the statement"
But there is a return before the end of the statement?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it's closed at the end of the statement (in that case the `return` **is** the *end of the statement*).